# I have problem with series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n} {n^2+1}z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n} {n^2+1}z^n$

I calculate derivative $ S'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2} {n^2+1}z^{n-1}$ and later $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+1-1} {n^2+1}z^{n-1}$ so we have 
$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+1} {n^2+1}z^{n-1}  - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1} {n^2+1}z^{n-1}$ and first series is easy, but how calculate second?

Comment: When plugging into Maple, the answer came out in terms of the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function). It doesn't look promising.

Answer (score 1):

As Theo Bendit commented $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n} {n^2+1}z^n$$ is not the must funny you could find.

Writing
$$\frac{n} {n^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{ n+i}+\frac{1}{ n-i}\right)$$ you end with
$$S=\frac{1+i}{4} z\, [\, _2F_1(1+i,2;2+i;z)-i \,
   _2F_1(1-i,2;2-i;z)]$$ where appears the Gaussian hypergeometric function.

If $z$ is real, $S$ is real only if $-\infty < z <1$